# talend - one tOracleInput to multiple tMap and tOutputFile

Tags: talend, talend-mdm

I'm wondering if I can query only once using `tOracleInput`, and use its output to two `tMap`.

```
             tMap   -> tOutputFile
             /

tOracleInput
             \
            tMap   -> tOutputFile
```

I have tried connecting `tOracleInput` to one more map, but it seems I can only linked it to one.

Any ideas?

Thank you1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use tReplicate component to use the single input given to two tMap.

[image]